# Winform Checkbox MouseDown event handler not allowing CheckedChanged event to fire

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, mousedown

I have a WinForm which contains a multitude of controls interdependent on each other for their visibility and content. 
I have a pair of radio buttons, controlling a combobox's (ComboBoxA) enable/disable flag and content. The selection on this combobox controls the visibility of a checkbox. The checking of this checkbox controls another combobox's (ComboBoxB) visibility and content. Business requirements are quite complicated around these controls. As a result, I require the ability to fire of the events programmatically and through user action, doing different things in each case.

In the checkbox's case, I check it programmatically while loading data (if needed), which fires the CheckedChanged event which in turn does additional action controlling ComboBoxB. The code for this is pretty vanilla, nothing special, but my question is more theoretical than practical. Please keep reading.

Due to this requirement, I need a way to distinguish between programmatic checking and user action. I tried using the Click event and CheckedChanged event, setting a flag in the click event, signifying user action. Unfortunately, the CheckedChanged event fires before the Click event, dead-ending this trick.

Now, I tried using the MouseDown event to capture user action. But funnily enough, once the event fires, checkbox remains unchecked and the CheckedChanged event doesnt fire.

Now, I have managed to use a flag in the code to determine programmatic checking and use that to distinguish between the two, but I was curious as to why the MouseDown event didnt allow the checkbox to be checked. Any ideas? I searched online but either I didnt do a thorough job of it, or google is not returning the right results for me. I apologize if anybody is actually able to find a google result for this problem.

Comment: goin to click on combobox ? and that click should trigger checkbox?

Comment: If you know you're about to change it programmatically, can you set a flag which you can then pickup on your CheckChanged event ? Reset the flag once finished

Comment: @utility, Yes, the checkbox is a legal disclaimer of sorts which should be asked only if certain selections are made on the combobox. Its a financial product and a lot of legal requirements drive the UI behavior.

Comment: @andrew, That is what I ended up doing. Since I couldnt set the flag to true based on user action and then reset it later, I decided to set the flag to true based on programmatic action instead, which was much easier, since the programmatic setting happens in a separate method called as part of the form load. But my question was more to understand the checkbox's event handlers' behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's something else in your code, not the `MouseDown` event that's preventing the `CheckChanged` to be fired.
Here is how I know this:
I've added a checkbox and a button to an empty form, and added event handlers to `Click` on the button, and on the checkbox `CheckedChanged`, `KeyDown` and `MouseDown` events. I've also added to the form a string variable called `LastEventRaised`, and in the CheckedChanged I've simply shown a `MessageBox`:

```
string LastEventRaised = string.Empty;
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Checked changed " + LastEventRaised);
    LastEventRaised = string.Empty;
}

private void checkBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    LastEventRaised = "KeyDown";
}

private void checkBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    LastEventRaised = "MouseDown";
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LastEventRaised = "programmatically";
    checkBox1.Checked = !checkBox1.Checked;
}
```

Each time the message box popped up I've got the correct message.

Comment: You are right. I tried your code and it behaved like you said. I compared it with mine and I did not see anything different that I am doing. Only thing different is that we created custom controls for the standard Windows forms controls based on standardized behavior required for the application, but for the checkbox and combobox atleast, there is no modification to the existing behavior of the controls, only some additional logic added to handle certain scenarios. Please give me some time, I will reply to this thread with the code that I used. Maybe that would give you guys more insight.

Comment: I tried upvoting it but i dont have enough reputation for it. :) Thanks for your code.